# How to add and package the new functionality when developing a new gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I've just created a sample gem called [maker](https://github.com/boddhisattva/maker). I'm also using RVM.

The recent changes to add a sample user functionality is present in [this PR](https://github.com/boddhisattva/maker/pull/1/files). I've been following [this guide](http://bundler.io/v1.16/guides/creating_gem.html) in the Bundler docs to create a new gem.

I'm currently trying to use the gem via irb and when I do a `require maker` I get the below error:

```
 :001 > require 'maker'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- maker/user
    from /Users/mohnishgj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/mohnishgj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/mohnishgj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@experiments/gems/maker-0.1.0/lib/maker.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/mohnishgj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `require'
    from /Users/mohnishgj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/mohnishgj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/mohnishgj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
 :002 >
```

When I navigate my way to where the gem is installed wrt the `experiments` gemset(i.e, `/Users/mohnishgj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@experiments/gems/maker-0.1.0`, I clearly see
that the `user.rb` file is missing from that location.

```
/Users/mohnishgj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@experiments/gems/maker-0.1.0/lib/maker
➜  maker ls
version.rb
```

How do I fix this whenever I want to add new files as part of the gem and want it to work out of `irb` . **Am I doing some part of gem related development wrongly** ? Please excuse my ignorance, I'm relatively new with creating gems. **How should I be doing gem related development from source correctly?**

Also, I could be possibly missing something but when I tried adding `Bundler.require(:default, :development)` to maker.gemspec(as suggested in the [guide to create the gem](http://bundler.io/v1.16/guides/creating_gem.html)) like

```
lib = File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require "maker/version"
Bundler.require(:default, :development)
```

I got errors like below:

```
[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`:  - [!] There was an error while loading `maker.gemspec`:  - [!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`:  - [!] There was an error while loading `maker.gemspec`:  - [!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`:
```

What could I be missing here?

Comment: You haven't packaged up `user.rb` and I don't even see it in the repo, so where did this get to? Are you sure you checked it in and pushed up your changes?

Comment: @tadman Thank you for trying to help out. `user.rb` is in the PR here(as mentioned in the question) - https://github.com/boddhisattva/maker/pull/1/files. How exactly do I package my gem everytime I make changes to it ? Also, how does that latest packaged gem then get into the appropriate gemset directory(/Users/mohnishgj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@experiments/gems/maker) ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is to use `bundle console` as mentioned in this post - http://wsmoak.net/2016/07/10/ruby-gem-dev-irb.html